# How to monitor system resource usage without showing process list

Tags: htop

I want to monitor system resources usage, the htop works very well, but I don't care processes now, is it possible to hide process list parts? Or, is there any other tool can do that?

Comment: I am not aware of anything to turn off the process list in `htop` but maybe consider `btop` that is a snap app that allows you to turn off the process list from showing.

Comment: @Terrance It is nice, I've updated the question, please provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to not show the processes in `htop`, but if you go with a similar alternative like `btop` or `bpytop` you can turn off the showing of the processes by pressing <kbd>4</kbd> on the keyboard.

Examples:

**BTOP:**  To install `btop` it is `sudo snap install btop`.  Then to run it just `btop` from a terminal window.

*`btop` with processes:*

[image]

*`btop` without processes:*

[image]

**BPYTOP:** To install `bpytop` it is `pip3 install bpytop`.  Then to run it just `bpytop` from a terminal window.

*`bpytop` with processes:*

[image]

*`bpytop` without processes:*

[image]

Hope this helps!